# Listen on nftables firewall ULOG logs

Tags: linux, sockets, go, linux-kernel, netlink

On [nftables](https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/) config logging is set with some group number in a rule:

```
table inet filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        # Log all
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 log group 1 prefix "input drop"
    }
}
```

you can see these logs with [ulogd](https://netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) default syslog config.

Is this correct way to listen on [nftables](https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/) ULOG rule logs?

```
fd, err := unix.Socket(syscall.AF_NETLINK, syscall.SOCK_RAW, unix.NFNL_SUBSYS_ULOG)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf(`socket: %w`, err))
}

err = unix.Bind(fd, &unix.SockaddrNetlink{
    Family: unix.NFNL_SUBSYS_ULOG,
    Groups: 1, // ?? Rule group?
    Pid:    0,
})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf(`bind: %w`, err))
}

buffer := make([]byte, os.Getpagesize())

for {
    for {
        // Peek for new messages
        n, _, err := unix.Recvfrom(fd, buffer, unix.MSG_PEEK)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf(`could not peek: %v`, err)
            continue
        }

        if n == 0 {
            continue
        }

        if n < len(buffer) {
            // We have new message(s), break loop and handle them
            break
        }

        // Make buffer larger if needed
        buffer = make([]byte, len(buffer)*2)
    }

    // Read out all available messages
    n, _, err := unix.Recvfrom(fd, buffer, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(`could not read messages: %v`, err)
        continue
    }

    if n == 0 {
        // Data length is zero, so go back to peeking new messages
        continue
    }

    msgs, err := syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage(buffer[:n])
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(`could not parse message: %v`, err)
        continue
    }

    for _, msg := range msgs {
        // Hex dump
        spew.Dump(msg)
        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("-", 80))
    }
}
```

Are these correct parameters on `unix.Socket(...)` and `unix.Bind(..)`? When data arrives from the kernel is the `syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage()` the correct way? Since changing almost any of the mentioned types the kernel message(s) also change radically since then you might be listening on wrong packet type.

I tried to read ulogd source but couldn't figure out if I have the correct parameters.

Comment: As I can see NETLINK_NFLOG is supported up to Linux 3.16 https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html

Comment: Thanks. ULOG seems to be the correct type. Changed the question.